# Error downloading .csv file in php from sql database

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to download '.csv' from phpmyadmin database but its downloading some blank files.
Same query works perfectly for sql in phpmyadmin. Below is the code:

```
function get_csv()
{ 
 $filename="c:/mydata.csv";
 $var=mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE $filename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\" FROM course");
 header("Content-type:  text/plain");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
 //print "$header\n$data";
 return 0;
}
```

On uncommenting the print statement I get a file with some error showing:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: header in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SEN_PROJECT_Latest\SEN-PROJECT\class\database.php</b> on line <b>485</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: data in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SEN_PROJECT_Latest\SEN-PROJECT\class\database.php</b> on line <b>485</b><br />
```

Comment: Where is $data defined in your function ?

Comment: I haven't and being nwebie I don't much idea about how to use it.

Comment: You are printing print "$header\n$data"; . So where is this $data coming from ? If you want to output the result of mysql query. Add a while loop to get the data and output it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you trying to download CSV file, no need to depend on other variables outside this function, just use readfile() you should see the file being downloaded.

```
function get_csv()
{ 
  $filename="c:\\mydata.csv";
  $var=mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE $filename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\" FROM course") or die(mysql_error());
  header("Content-type:  text/plain");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($filename);
  return 0;
}
```

If that code not downloaded the file, you can check the c:/mydata.csv and see if it's created or not.

Comment: I used the exact but the downloaded file contains some warning saying:<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(c:/mydata.csv) [<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SEN_PROJECT_Latest\SEN-PROJECT\class\database.php</b> on line <b>487</b><br />

Comment: Use updated code, i changed `c:/mydata.csv` to `c:\\mydata.csv`, also, you should be connected to database before calling that function.

Comment: I did that too ,but still no luck.

Comment: Worked now,it was not working as I was not removing already existing files.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file name in `INTO OUTFILE` needs to be a string literal:

```
"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$filename' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\" FROM course"
```